# How do I fix multiple redirects to my mobile site on Blogger?

Tags: html, redirect, google-pagespeed

One of the numerous suggestions made by Google Page Speed Insights regarding my slow as yuck website is:

> Avoid multiple redirects. Redirects introduce additional delays before
>   the page can be loaded. Learn more. URL Time Spent (Initial:
>   http://okc-craigslist.blogspot.com/) 0 ms
>   /?m=1(okc-craigslist.blogspot.com) 630 ms
>   /?m=1(okc-craigslist.blogspot.com) 180 ms

Can someone tell me what this means exactly? I don't know why I would be redirecting twice to the mobile version of my website. How do I fix this?

Help!

Answer (score 1):

If you mouse over the two links in the PageSpeed output, you can see that the first starts with `http://`, and the second `https://`. The first redirect changes the query string, and the second the scheme.

Ideally the first redirect would send you to both HTTPS and mobile version of the site, but that might not be possible for you to control.

Perhaps Blogger can turn on [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)? That will teach the user's browser to apply the http→https redirect to the entire site.

Comment: Thank you for answering :-) I'm embarrassed that I didn't see the http/https. Regardless, Google says it's a problem that I need to fix. Blogger is Google's platform so surely there's a solution. I'll check into HSTS. I've been confused about what Blogger will allow ever since they forcibly switched everyone to https. And I've never understood why they redirect to mobile version.

Comment: "PageSpeed Insights (PSI) reports on the performance of a page on both mobile and desktop devices" https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid multiple page redirection for Following Steps :
Go to "Edit HTML" of your blog/blogger.com or website.

Add below code just after  tag of your blog:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
var curl = window.location.href;if (curl.indexOf('m=1') != -1) {curl = curl.replace('m=1', 'm=0');window.location.href = curl;}
//]]></script>
```

and Save it .
it will works fine 
here is [Demo website](https://2020spammer.blogspot.com) that it works fine on blogger

Comment: This is not solution as it redirects two time. When you access Demo web site with mobile useragent then you will be redirected to m=0 then redirect again m=1. Any solutions?